# C# T-SQL Join and Union

Tags: c#, sql, join, union-all

I have a question regarding **joining tables**.

I have eleven tables, one parent with ten child tables. **Primary key on all is EventName** with the relationship from parent to child being EventName as well. The child tables names are SR1Laptimes, SR2Laptimes etc x 10.

The schema in the child tables are identical. I'm trying to join Events table to SR1Laptimes and then **Union all the child table together** but can't get it to work.

There is a method behind this madness but would take some time to explain. Here's the code anyway, any feed back would be greatly appreciated. P.S the codes not finished in this copy and paste.

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT MIN(Q1), MIN(Q2), MIN(Q3), MIN(Q4), MIN(LaptimesMinutes), MIN(LaptimesSeconds) FROM Events LEFT JOIN SR1Laptimes ON Events.EventName = SR1Laptimes.EventName SELECT * FROM SR1Laptimes UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SR2Laptimes UNION ALL SELECT * FROM SR3Laptimes WHERE (Events.Track = @track) AND (Events.Number = @number) AND (Events.Rider = @rider)";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@track", analysisTrackComboBox.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", analysisNumberComboBox.Text);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rider", analysisRiderComboBox.Text);
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing an `UNION ALL` clause at:

```
 ... ON Events.EventName = SR1Laptimes.EventName *HERE* SELECT * FROM SR1Laptimes ...
```

Comment: I did have it in there but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

Are the tables you try to 'union all' have same columns? That might be the problem.

And 'where' clause at the end is valid only for SR3Laptimes.

Comment: The child tables are identical in columns, data types and number of columns.

Comment: I tried to put the join and union in various structures using parentheses but it didn't help (regards where clause)

Answer (score 0):

This example may help you.

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (id INT,sth NVARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @ChildTest1 TABLE(id INT,parentId INT, sth NVARCHAR(100))

DECLARE @ChildTest2 TABLE(id INT, parentId INT, sth NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @Parent
SELECT 1,'Ali'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Veli'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'Ahmet'


INSERT INTO @ChildTest1
SELECT 1,1,'Parent1_Child1_1strow'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'Parent1_Child1_2ndrow'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,2,'Parent2_Child1_1strow'


INSERT INTO @ChildTest2
SELECT 1,1,'Parent1_Child2_1strow'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,2,'Parent2_Child2_1strow'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3,'Parent3_Child2_1strow'

SELECT * FROM @Parent p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM @ChildTest1 ct1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * FROM @ChildTest2 ct2
) s ON p.id =s.parentId
--WHERE p.id = 3
```